# Issue with asp Image and file upload controls in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, firefox, file-upload

I have an Image control which is used to display image on click of a button. The code is as below:

**.aspx code**

```
<asp:Image ID="imgCorrect" runat="server" Height="175px" Width="150px" ImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/NoPreviewShareHR_Grey.jpg" />

<asp:FileUpload ID="FlUpldImage" runat="server" Width="200px" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="valUp" ControlToValidate="FlUpldImage"
ErrorMessage="Image Files Only (.jpg, .bmp, .png, .gif)" ValidationGroup="ImageFormat"
ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.JPG|.gif|.GIF|.jpeg|.JPEG|.bmp|.BMP|.png|.PNG)$" />

<asp:Button ID="btnImageUpload" runat="server" Text="Preview" OnClick="btnImageUpload_Click" CausesValidation="false"/>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HidnLocalImageURL" runat="server" Value=""/>
```

**C# Code**

```
protected void btnImageUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String fileToUpload = Convert.ToString(FlUpldImage.PostedFile.FileName);
    HidnLocalImageURL.Value = fileToUpload;
    if (fileToUpload != "")
        imgCorrect.ImageUrl = fileToUpload;
    else
        imgCorrect.ImageUrl = "~/_layouts/images/NoPrview.jpg";
}
```

The above code works fine on IE but gives issue in Mozilla Firefox:

- The RE validator for file upload shows error message as invalid image even if proper
  image is selected and
- onclick of `btnImageUpload` the image control    **disappears**. This
  issue occurs on Firefox browser only and works fine    in IE.

`fileToUpload`  in C# code contains the prope path to the image including drive letter. I don't want to physically store the files into application folder as this is just to preview the image.

Kindly help me to sort out both issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log FlUpldImage.PostedFile.FileName.

I think firefox sends only filename not full path.
If so, its better to use simple textbox and paste path in it without dialogbox.

Answer (score 0):

As a security precaution, references to images on your local computer from a remote web site are disabled. If you encounter this restriction and you understand the security implications, you can disable this security measure.

for more info
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Images_or_animations_don%27t_load